# Bluetooth service not starting, console says: sandboxd blued deny file-read-metadata

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bluetooth, osx-mavericks, iobluetooth

I have an app that uses IOBluetooth to register itself as a Bluetooth service and set itself to auto-start when receiving an incoming RFCOMM connection.

It was working on OS X Lion.

However on Mavericks, the app doesn't start, and if I open console, I see this:

```
sandboxd[314]: ([83]) blued(83) deny file-read-metadata /Applications/MyBluetoothApp.app
```

It looks like sandboxd is blocking me.  Why?  Shouldn't the IOBluetooth API's take care of this?
How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Maybe an entitlement issue?  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW11

Comment: Maybe!  Thanks I am looking now...

Comment: App Sandbox was introduced in OS X v10.7 Lion, and my app was working fine then.  So is that really the issue?  Anyway, the console message seems to suggest that blued has "entitlement" issues, as it is the one supposed to launch my app (my app is not even running when that message is logged).

Comment: The details of sandboxing change from release to release.  Entitlements can control more than just your app's behavior, but also interaction between the system and your app.  It was a guess, hence presented as a comment, because I'm not sure what the real problem might be.

Comment: Just confirmed that my app isn't using the sandbox.

Comment: Thus leaving me with not a clue!  Sorry.